# How can I minimise connections with django-celery when using CloudAMQP through dotcloud?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, dotcloud, cloudamqp

After spending a few weeks getting django-celery-rabbitmq working on dotcloud I have discovered that dotcloud is no longer supporting rabbitmq. Instead they recommend CloudAMQP. So I've set up CloudAMQP as per the tutorials:

- http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/python/django-celery/
- http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/more/cloudamqp/
- http://www.cloudamqp.com/docs-dotcloud.html

And the service works fine. However, even when I do not have any processes running, CloudAMQP says there are 3 connections.

I had a look at their docs and they say (http://www.cloudamqp.com/docs-python.html) for celery it's best to set

```
broker_pool_limit = 1
```

I have now done this but the connections remain at 3. Any idea how I can

- reduce the number of connections to 0 when the app is not in use?
- minimise the number of connections to ensure that I remain
  within my quota?

Comment: I think it's case sensitive, so it should be ```BROKER_POOL_LIMIT=1``` http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/configuration.html#broker-pool-limit

Comment: Note that the 'amqp' result backend will require more connections as it needs at least one connection per pool process (e.g. --concurrency=3 will require 3 extra connections).