# Celery Cloudamqp creates new connection for each task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, cloudamqp

I am currently using nitrous.io running Django with Celery and then Cloudamqp as my broker with the free plan (max 3 connections). I'm able to connect just fine and start up a periodic task just fine.

When I run

```
    celery -A proj worker  -l info
```

2 connections are created immediately on Cloudamqp and I am able to manually create multiple tasks on a 3rd connection and all is well. However, when I run celery beat with

```
    celery -A proj worker -B -l info
```

all 3 connections are used and if celery beat creates 1 or more new tasks, another 4th connection will be created thus going over the maximum connections allowed.

I've tried and currently have set

```
    BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
```

but that doesn't seem to limit the connections
I've also tried

```
    celery -A proj worker -B -l info
    celery -A proj worker -B -l info -c 1  
    celery -A proj worker -B -l info --autoscale=1,1  -c 1
```

with no luck.

Why is there 2 connections made immediately that are doing nothing?
Is there someway limit the initial celery connections to 0 or 1 or have the tasks share/run on the celery beat connection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Celery creating a new connection for each task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013220/celery-creating-a-new-connection-for-each-task)

Answer (score 1):

While it does not actually limit connections, another user found that disabling the connection pool reduced the number of connections in practice:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23563018/1867779

`BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 0`

The Redis and Mongo backends have their own connection limit parameters.

- http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/configuration.html#celery-redis-max-connections
- http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/configuration.html#celery-mongodb-backend-settings (using the `max_pool_size` parameter)

The AMQP backend does not have such a setting.

- http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/configuration.html#amqp-backend-settings

Given that, I'm not sure what `BROKER_POOL_LIMIT` is meant to do, but I'd really like to see `CELERY_AMQP_MAX_CONNECTIONS`.

Here's a related, unanswered question: [How can I minimise connections with django-celery when using CloudAMQP through dotcloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741753/)